# Windows Batch help loop for /l

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Hello i would like help for tic tac toe ..
I want to do something when the 1st and the 2nd case is checked by a player ..

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
set case9=player
set case13=player
set case17=player
for /l %%a in (9, 4, 17) do (
    set x_case%%a=!case%%a!
    if "!x_case%%a!"=="player" if "!x_case%%a+%%a!"=="player" (
        batbox /g 17 14 /d " X "
    )
)
pause
```

It's named case 9 13 17 because of the length of the console and the tic tac toe grid. I want help and explanation about how can i do %%a + %%a, i tried

```
set plus_case=%%a+4
echo !case%plus_case%!
```

but it still don't work because we're in for section ...
Thanks you for help and can you help me to find a title, i don't know what title can i put.

Comment: Use `set /A plus_case=%%a+4` and then `call echo %%case!plus_case!%%` or `for %%i in (!plus_case!) do echo !case%%i!`. This management is explained at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to compare - but even had your code worked as you expected, you would be comparing `case9` to `case18`, `case13` to `case26` and `case17` to `case34`.

Even by adding 4, you'd be comparing `case17` to `case21`

If you want to see whether at least 2 of the variables contain `player` then

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
set case9=player
set case13=player
set case17=player
set match=0
for /l %%a in (9, 4, 17) do (
    if "!case%%a!"=="player" set /a match+=1
)
if %match% geq 2  batbox /g 17 14 /d " X "

pause
```

Now quite what you actually want is not clear. The above line will execute `batbox` if 2 or 3 (`G`reater or `EQ`ual to 2) "player"s are found. If you want *exactly* 2, change `geq` to `equ`. If they have to be `case13` and either `case9` or `case17` then it's probably easier to use

```
if "%case13%"=="player" if "%case13%"=="%case9%" (batbox /g 17 14 /d " X "
) else if "%case13%"=="%case17%" (batbox /g 17 14 /d " X ")
```

Comment: in fact, i want to do `if "%case9%"=="checkbyplayer" and if "%case9%"=="checkbyplayer" set check13=checkbycomputer` and `if "%case17%"=="checkbyplayer" and if "%case13%"=="checkbyplayer" set check9=checkbycomputer` or `if "%case9%"=="checkbycomputer" and if "%case9%"=="checkbycomputer" set check13=checkbyplayer` and `if "%case17%"=="checkbycomputer" and if "%case13%"=="checkbycomputer" set check9=checkbyplayer` but more simply for my tic tac toe ... thanks for your proposition i misspoke.